# AdWhirl custom event noSuchMethodException?

Tags: android, adwhirl

today I tried integrating the TapForTap network with AdWhirl and a custom event. Apparently many people have been able to achieve this without any errors, but I wasn't one of them. My code is my ad class that loads my ads whenever it is initialised. Here is my Ad.java class: http://pastebin.com/TppQeqUh and the error that I then see in LogCat: http://pastebin.com/pv4Rpz8U . Thank you and I hope someone can help me with my problem :)

Comment: Anyone? This problem looks like it is easy to fix :S

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up using Admob Mediation, which is basically the same thing.

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure nothing is inadvertently modifying `adWhirlLayout`'s `adWhirlInterface` property?  I've been able to get things working properly with our sample code, so it seems like either `adWhirlLayout.adWhirlInterface` isn't pointing to the right place, or you've got a typo somewhere (which I didn't find in your code).

Comment: I use Eclipse so it should recognise typos. Idk im trying AdMob Ad mediation now